# Postgres server running on EC2 closing every once in while. Unable to isolate the issue here

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.2

I have a database connection configured on my Django application to a Postgres server. 
This server is running on an EC2 instance.
Every once in a while (3 times as of this post) I see this when I run my django App

```
  Is the server running on host "xx.com" (13.xx.xx.xx) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I run this : `sudo service postgresql status`
I get

```
postmaster dead but pid file exists
```

and when I run `sudo service postgresql restart` I get

```
Stopping postgresql service:                               [FAILED]
Starting postgresql service:                               [  OK  ]
```

I tried deleting postmaster.pid file in /var/lib/pgsql9/data
But that does not seem to solve the problem.

It seems to work fine when I restart the server. But that is *Windows-user* type solution I am using.

-- I am still new to using postgres.

Here is what the log file (in /var/lib/pgsql9/data/pg_log) had when the server went down:

```
sh: line 46: kill: (5102) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5103) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5105) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5106) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5126) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5127) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5130) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5150) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5151) - No such process
sh: line 46: kill: (5154) - No such process
```

Comment: Could be anything: hardware/maintenace failure, quota, OOM, ... Do you have access to the PG logfile?

Comment: Yes, I have access to a root user in the machine. Added logs to my questions.

Comment: Provide full pg logs, check system logs. Maybe pg crashes dues oom

Comment: @Anton Could you please let me know which logs to look for, a bit new to this part of the Tech tree. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is clearly not able to reach to the server.
The error states that the application/client is trying to find a server on xx.com where it cannot find the postmaster service running on port 5432 and accepting connections.

From the other information you provided, it looks like there's something killing the postmaster at backend and when this happens the postmaster.pid file is not removed. And as long as there's a postmaster.pid file, the service status will show this message `postmaster dead but pid file exists`.

Try looking into the database logs (/pg_log) for more information on the crash part.

Comment: Hi, I added the snippet from log file, when the server crashed. Hope this helps. Let me know of any other logs that might help me understand this better.

Comment: The logs you attached are probably from the time when you executed 'sudo service postgresql restart' as it was looking for the services to terminate, however, none of them was present.
Check logs before these lines or the OS logs to check what caused server termination/crash.